# Calculate the difference between a date and the current date

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ms-access, datediff

I am creating a program with C# which interfaces with a Microsoft Access Database.  My current task is to capture the date/time an entry was created and calculate the difference between the stored value and the current date and display that in a cell.  What I am not sure about is whether to do the calculations in C# and then store them in the database or store the information in the database first and then perform the calculations with SQL.

I also need to track how long a unit has been classified under a specific status code.  I need to track the date/time the status code was changed and calculate the difference in days between the date the status code was changed and the current date.

For example...if Unit xyz is a had its status code changed on 3/5 and the current date is 3/8...I want it to show that it has been in limbo for 3 days.

The whole purpose of this is to determine where the bottlenecks are in the production process.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional and Microsoft Access 2010.  The database is stored as a .mdb file.

I am sorry if this is a bit confusing.  I will be happy to edit my question, add additional details, and/or provide clarification to help answer this question.

**Edit For Code**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
        startTimeTextBox.Text = a.ToString();
    }

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime b = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

These are the only two bits of code that I have tried.  I have also tried doing the calculations in Access with Now() - StartDate with limited success.

Comment: Show the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: *"doing the calculations in Access with Now() - StartDate with limited success"*  Seems like that should work if `StartDate` is an Access Date/Time field.  What were the limitations you mentioned?

Comment: I stated it worked with limited success because while it did display the difference, it was displayed as a decimal and I could not figure out how to display only the number of days.  When I determined I was going to have issues with that method, I decided to ask the question.

Comment: @HansUp is right: Now() - StartDate expression will work, returning the value representing DateTime (Integer part for Days and decimal part for the fraction of 24 hours). It could be converted to Days diff using expression DiffDays2: Fix(Now()-[StartDate]); multiple alternative (recommended) solutions are shown in the answer. Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task can be completed in several different ways as per the following examples:

in MS Office/Access VBA using the function:

```
DateDiff ( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear])
```

e.g. (diff in days):

`DateDiff("d",[StartDate],Now())`

or diff in sec:

`DateDiff("s",[StartDate],Now())`

and also calculating difference in days using MS Access SQL query like shown below (RECOMMENDED):

```
SELECT StartDate, DateDiff("d",[StartDate],Now()) AS DiffDays FROM Table1;
```

***Note***: pertinent to your computational sample, it could be also programmed in MS Access SQL as the following (NOT recommended because of possible errors while processing negative values):

```
SELECT StartDate, Fix(Now()-[StartDate]) AS DiffDays2  FROM Table1;
```

It could be also calculated in C# as per the answer given by member @JaredPrice, or using similar `DateAndTime.DateDiff()` method available in .NET/C# (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127413(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
long _diffDays = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, StartDate, DateTime.Now);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This helped massively!  This was one of the best and most helpful answers I have ever received.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Likewise, thanks for the appreciation and good luck with your project! Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

```
var seconds = DateTime.Now.Subtract(yourDateTimeObject).TotalSeconds;
```

Gives you difference in seconds. Hopefully that helps. You can also get totals of other stuff like `TotalMilliseconds`.

Also, `DateTime.Now` gets the current time as a `DateTime` object. You could also compare two `DateTime` objects by doing something like `var seconds = oneDateTimeObject.Subtract(anotherDateTimeObject).TotalSeconds;`.